# TLS 1.0 has been disabled in this organization. Please use TLS 1.1 or higher when connecting to Salesforce using https

Tags: soap-api, tls, critical-update

Error message:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:sf="urn:fault.enterprise.soap.sforce.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
       <soapenv:Body>
          <soapenv:Fault>
             <faultcode>sf:UNSUPPORTED_CLIENT</faultcode>
             <faultstring>UNSUPPORTED_CLIENT: TLS 1.0 has been disabled in this organization. Please use TLS 1.1 or higher when connecting to Salesforce using https.</faultstring>
             <detail>
                <sf:UnexpectedErrorFault xsi:type="sf:UnexpectedErrorFault">
                   <sf:exceptionCode>UNSUPPORTED_CLIENT</sf:exceptionCode>
                   <sf:exceptionMessage>TLS 1.0 has been disabled in this organization. Please use TLS 1.1 or higher when connecting to Salesforce using https.</sf:exceptionMessage>
                </sf:UnexpectedErrorFault>
             </detail>
          </soapenv:Fault>
       </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>
```

But, Critical Updates are not showing the option for "Require TLS 1.1 or higher for HTTPS connections". How can I enable this option in my organization?

[image: Critical Updates Page, without Option for TLS]

Comment: Here is detailed article from Salesforce help providing detailed information and action items to resolve same https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000221207

Comment: Sandboxes only acception TLS 1.1 and higher. You can disable it in developer or prod environment but only for a limited time. (I think until March 2017 after then it will only accept TLS 1.1 and higher)

Comment: Require TLS 1.1 or higher for HTTPS connections   this option avilable prodction but sandbox is not avilable

Comment: Please contact salesforce support. This option has disappeared for the sandbox orgs this year.

Comment: @Mukesh - I already have the system admin permissions. Also I am using Java 8 latest version 1.8.0_131, but still issue exist.

Answer (score 4):

It is clearly stated in [Salesforce disabling TLS 1.0](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000221207). Note this option is **completely unavailable for sandbox environments**:

> June 25, 2016, at 9:30 AM PDT (16:30 UTC)
>   After this date and time, all sandbox orgs -- whether existing, refreshed, or new -- will have TLS 1.0 automatically disabled and will require TLS 1.1 or later in HTTPS connections to or from the sandbox org. The "Require TLS 1.1 or higher for HTTPS connections" CRUC setting will not be available.

For Production environments, make sure you have the proper permissions:

> **Permissions Required**
>   A user must have the following permissions:
>
> - View the CRUC setting: View Setup and Configuration
> - Activate or Deactivate the CRUC setting: Customize Application and Modify All Data

More complete timeline information:

> ### When will Salesforce disable TLS 1.0 encryption?
>
> The timeframes for disabling the use of TLS 1.0 to and from Salesforce can be found below. Each listed service must be compatible with TLS 1.1 or later by the dates below.
>
> ---
>
> **Service**
>   New production
>   orgs created with Summer '16 or later
>
> **TLS 1.0 Disablement Schedule**
>   TLS 1.0 is disabled by default.
>
> New production orgs created with Summer ‘16 or later will have the "Require TLS 1.1 or higher for HTTPS connections” Critical Update Console (CRUC) setting auto-enabled. This will disable TLS 1.0 by default.
>
> This setting can be deactivated by the customer to enable TLS 1.0 as needed for TLS compatibility testing. See the [article](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?urlname=TLS-1-0-Disablement-Critical-Update-Console-CRUC-Setting&language=en_US) for details on user permissions required to view and change the setting.
>
> ---
>
> **Service**
>   Sandbox orgs
>
> **TLS 1.0 Disablement Schedule**
>   June 25, 2016, at 9:30 AM PDT (16:30 UTC)
>   After this date and time, all sandbox orgs -- whether existing, refreshed, or new -- will have TLS 1.0 automatically disabled and will require TLS 1.1 or later in HTTPS connections to or from the sandbox org. The "Require TLS 1.1 or higher for HTTPS connections" CRUC setting will not be available.
>
> ---
>
> **Service**
>   Production orgs
>
> **TLS 1.0 Disablement Schedule**
>   March 4, 2017, at 9:30 AM PST (17:30 UTC)
>
> ---
>
> **Service**
>   login.salesforce.com, other services*
>
> **TLS 1.0 Disablement Schedule**
>   Early 2017

Answer (score 2):

I have faced the exact same issue when I try to connect to the salesforce org from Eclipse Kepler ,

And I changed the eclipse from Eclipse Kepler to Eclipse Mars and This error was eliminated.

However at what point you got this error, If you were getting it in the Eclipse then try the option I have shared.